# iOS : Autorelease Pool in AppDelegate using MFMailComposeViewController in Picker View

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, autorelease

How to avoid autorelease pool in my AppDelegate in my picker view. When I click a button called email, my program crash.

Here is my code snippet :

```
-(void)pickerViewEmail:(UIPickerView *)pickerViewEmail didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{

    if ([[musicList objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"m1"])
    {

        MFMailComposeViewController *pickerEmail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        pickerEmail.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"m1" ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSData *m1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

        [pickerEmail addAttachmentData:m1 mimeType:@"audio/mp3" fileName:@"m1"];

        [pickerEmail setSubject:@"Hello"];

        // Set up recipients
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"]; 
        NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", 

        [pickerEmail setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        [pickerEmail setCcRecipients:ccRecipients]; 


        // Fill out the email body text
        NSString *emailBody = @"Hello";
        [pickerEmail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

        [self presentModalViewController:pickerEmail animated:YES];
        [pickerEmail release];

    }

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{   
    message.hidden = NO;

    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            message.text = @"Email canceled";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            message.text = @"Email saved";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            message.text = @"Email sent";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            message.text = @"Email failed";
            break;
        default:
            message.text = @"Email not sent";
            break;
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


-(IBAction)showEmail
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {

        self.emailButton.enabled = YES ;
        [self performSelector:@selector(pickerViewEmail:didSelectRow:inComponent:) 
                   withObject:audioPlayer];

           }

   else

    {


    NSString *recipients = @"mailto:first@example.com?cc=second@example.com,third@example.com&subject=Hello!";
    NSString *body = @"&body=Hello";

    NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", recipients, body];
    email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];

    }

}
```

When I press that IBAction button, the program shows this line code error.

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

How to avoid this matter?

Here is my console output:

```
[Switching to process 4452 thread 0x1f03]
[Switching to process 4452 thread 0x207]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c


0x0026f97f  <+0891>  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x0026f982  <+0894>  call   0x70a8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x0026f987  <+0899>  mov    %eax,%esi
0x0026f989  <+0901>  mov    0x69940e(%edi),%eax
0x0026f98f  <+0907>  mov    0x68db46(%edi),%ecx
0x0026f995  <+0913>  lea    0x525009(%edi),%edx
0x0026f99b  <+0919>  mov    %edx,0x8(%esp)
0x0026f99f  <+0923>  mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
0x0026f9a3  <+0927>  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x0026f9a6  <+0930>  call   0x70a8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x0026f9ab  <+0935>  mov    0x68df86(%edi),%ecx
0x0026f9b1  <+0941>  mov    %ebx,0x18(%esp)
0x0026f9b5  <+0945>  lea    0x6a6c56(%edi),%edx
0x0026f9bb  <+0951>  mov    %edx,0x14(%esp)
0x0026f9bf  <+0955>  mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
0x0026f9c3  <+0959>  mov    %esi,0x8(%esp)
0x0026f9c7  <+0963>  mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
0x0026f9cb  <+0967>  mov    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
0x0026f9ce  <+0970>  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x0026f9d1  <+0973>  movl   $0x641,0x10(%esp)
0x0026f9d9  <+0981>  call   0x70a8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x0026f9de  <+0986>  mov    0x699476(%edi),%eax
0x0026f9e4  <+0992>  mov    0x68db72(%edi),%ecx
0x0026f9ea  <+0998>  mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
0x0026f9ee  <+1002>  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x0026f9f1  <+1005>  call   0x70a8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x0026f9f6  <+1010>  mov    0x68df92(%edi),%ecx
0x0026f9fc  <+1016>  mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
0x0026fa00  <+1020>  mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
0x0026fa04  <+1024>  mov    -0x10(%ebp),%esi
0x0026fa07  <+1027>  mov    %esi,(%esp)
0x0026fa0a  <+1030>  call   0x70a8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x0026fa0f  <+1035>  mov    0x6d0fbe(%edi),%ebx
0x0026fa15  <+1041>  test   %al,%al
0x0026fa17  <+1043>  je     0x26fa2c <UIApplicationMain+1064>
0x0026fa19  <+1045>  mov    0x68dbb6(%edi),%eax
0x0026fa1f  <+1051>  mov    %ebx,0x8(%esp)
0x0026fa23  <+1055>  mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x0026fa27  <+1059>  mov    %ebx,(%esp)
0x0026fa2a  <+1062>  jmp    0x26fa69 <UIApplicationMain+1125>
0x0026fa2c  <+1064>  mov    0x68dc0a(%edi),%eax
0x0026fa32  <+1070>  mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x0026fa36  <+1074>  mov    %esi,(%esp)
0x0026fa39  <+1077>  call   0x70a8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x0026fa3e  <+1082>  mov    0x68dcba(%edi),%ecx
0x0026fa44  <+1088>  mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
0x0026fa48  <+1092>  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x0026fa4b  <+1095>  call   0x70a8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x0026fa50  <+1100>  mov    0x68df96(%edi),%ecx
0x0026fa56  <+1106>  mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
0x0026fa5a  <+1110>  mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
0x0026fa5e  <+1114>  mov    %ebx,(%esp)
0x0026fa61  <+1117>  movl   $0x1,0xc(%esp)
0x0026fa69  <+1125>  call   0x70a8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x0026fa6e  <+1130>  mov    0x68db22(%edi),%eax
0x0026fa74  <+1136>  mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x0026fa78  <+1140>  mov    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
0x0026fa7b  <+1143>  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x0026fa7e  <+1146>  call   0x70a8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x0026fa83  <+1151>  mov    0x6d0fbe(%edi),%eax
0x0026fa89  <+1157>  mov    0x68df9a(%edi),%ecx
0x0026fa8f  <+1163>  mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
0x0026fa93  <+1167>  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x0026fa96  <+1170>  call   0x70a8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x0026fa9b  <+1175>  xor    %eax,%eax
0x0026fa9d  <+1177>  add    $0x2c,%esp
0x0026faa0  <+1180>  pop    %esi
0x0026faa1  <+1181>  pop    %edi
0x0026faa2  <+1182>  pop    %ebx
0x0026faa3  <+1183>  pop    %ebp
0x0026faa4  <+1184>  ret
```

This line is causing the crash 
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error

Comment: how do you know this is an autorelease problem?  I don't see the word autorelease in your code or in your eeeny weeny log output snippet.

Comment: What line of code does it crash on?

Comment: The line of code is above. Here : return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

Comment: @Amink it's not really that line of code. Please show all the console output. There is probably something about an internal inconsistency error. Please add everything from your console to your question (at least the last ten lines of output)

Comment: I have added the console output at my question

Comment: Have you implemented the delegate method-mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error: ?

Comment: That can't be all your console output. Please include the part that shows the exception or error. If there really is no exception or error, try running with zombies enabled and see if you're sending a message to a deallocated instance.

Comment: @JasonCoco. I have amended my console output. And also already tick the zombies.I only have this return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));Thread 1 : program received signal "SIGABRT"

Comment: can u put the code of delegate method also here?

Comment: Here's the thing. I don't see the program received signal message in your console output above. Also your output looks like disassembly. Did you ask Xcode to disassemble a method for you? The reason it shows you that line in main is because when an exception is thrown in another thread, GDB mistakenly jumps to the bottom of the main threads stack. Your console should show what the actual exception is. You might also put a symbolic breakpoint on the abort(2) call.

Comment: @RIP. I have just put it on my question.

Comment: I think we need to see the backtrace... try entering 'bt' at the gdb console and posting that here.

Comment: @JasonCoco. wow this getting deeper for me as beginner. I never touch any disassemble. But I have xcode 4.0 & 4.3 installed in seperate destination. How to do that symbolic breakpoint on the abort(2) call? By the way, if i'm using 2 picker view delegate method : one for playing audio & one for email. Is it recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like something unhelpful is going on with your debugger / stack trace. There's another way to help pin down what / where your error is.

Put a breakpoint on

```
-(void)pickerViewEmail:(UIPickerView *)pickerViewEmail didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

// PUT BREAKPOINT HERE

if ([[musicList objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"m1"])
...
```

Then step through your code line by line until it crashes.

Once you have done that, edit your question and tell us which line is causing the crash.

Comment: This line is causing the crash - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error

Comment: Ok I have done that & edited my question. It works fine if I did it manually for 6 email selected button for the picker view

Comment: I don't understand your last comment :( What do you mean '6' ?

Comment: Previously I have one email button using if statement to delegate the email function for the picker view. Now I am using 6 small email button to delegate the email function for the picker view. One email delegate button for one row of picker view. I think not really smart. Haha. I don't know what to do since my knowledge is limited. :( If I can solve my previous question it will be a great help.